# Apache Atlas server not running,for check the reason 'zookeeper always send error message'

Tags: solr, apache-zookeeper, apache-atlas

I am new for Atlas and had try to install it for 3 days.It's to hard for to install. So can anyone help me solve this question,thanks all.

```
    WARN  - 2021-02-02 07:49:29.543; [   ] org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread; Session 0x200ad9fa8f00005 for server null, unexpected error, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:714)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.doTransport(ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:361)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1081)



 ERROR - 2021-02-02 07:54:26.835; [   ] org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$EventThread; Error while calling watcher
java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Task org.apache.solr.common.util.ExecutorUtil$MDCAwareThreadPoolExecutor$1@5527a145 rejected from org.apache.solr.common.util.ExecutorUtil$MDCAwareThreadPoolExecutor@10ea4804[Terminated, pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 21]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$AbortPolicy.rejectedExecution(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:2063)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.reject(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:830)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1379)
        at org.apache.solr.common.util.ExecutorUtil$MDCAwareThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ExecutorUtil.java:135)
        at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:112)
        at org.apache.solr.common.cloud.SolrZkClient$3.process(SolrZkClient.java:261)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$EventThread.processEvent(ClientCnxn.java:522)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$EventThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:498)
```